# why does my android app which uses GPS to find the current location encounters a crash, every time I run it? It shows a force close

Tags: android, android-emulator, crash, gps

I'.m developing this on Eclipse. 
My app aims at finding the current location using GPS, but when I run it on the emulator, it shows an unexpected force close. I have attached the main.xml, java file and manifest.xml.

**Main file:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".GooglemapsActivity" >

   <com.google.android.maps.MapView
android:id="@+id/mapview1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:enabled="true"
android:clickable="true"
android:apiKey="0o6t2Gs5-C0eAHL2ZNbwvzu4pwsgX50HX2X8rKA"
 />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Java file:**

```
package com.example.mapgp;   
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Menu;
import com.example.mapgp.R;
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Gmapwithgps extends MapActivity {
public MapView mapView;
public MapController mc;
public MyLocationListener locl;
public LocationManager manager;

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
{   
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
    {
        loc.getLatitude();
        loc.getLongitude();
        String Text = "My current location is: " +
        "Lati = " + loc.getLatitude() +
        "Longi = " + loc.getLongitude();
        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), Text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
    {
        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Gps Disabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
    {
        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Gps Enabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
    {

    }

}   

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gmapwithgps);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview1);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    mc = mapView.getController();

    manager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locl = new MyLocationListener();
    manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 35000, 10, this.locl);

}   

protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
     return false;
     }

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_gmapwithgps, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

**Manifest.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.example.mapgp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.mapgp.GmapwithgpsActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**Logcat:**

```
01-04 22:36:54.120: D/AndroidRuntime(1510): Shutting down VM
01-04 22:36:54.120: W/dalvikvm(1510): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught          exception (group=0x40015560)
01-04 22:36:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(1510): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-04 22:36:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(1510): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to   instantiate activity    ComponentInfo{com.example.mapgp/com.example.mapgp.GmapwithgpsActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.mapgp.GmapwithgpsActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/com.example.mapgp-1.apk]
01-04 22:36:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(1510):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
01-04 22:36:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(1510):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
01-04 22:36:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(1510):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-04 22:36:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(1510):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
01-04 22:36:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(1510):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-04 22:36:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(1510):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-04 22:36:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(1510):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-04 22:36:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(1510):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-04 22:36:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(1510):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-04 22:36:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(1510):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-04 22:36:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(1510):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-04 22:36:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(1510):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-04 22:36:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(1510): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.mapgp.GmapwithgpsActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/com.example.mapgp-1.apk]
01-04 22:36:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(1510):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
01-04 22:36:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(1510):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
01-04 22:36:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(1510):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
01-04 22:36:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(1510):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
01-04 22:36:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(1510):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
01-04 22:36:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(1510):     ... 11 more
01-04 22:37:24.730: I/Process(1510): Sending signal. PID: 1510 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Please paste logcat here also.

Comment: @TGMCians i've posted the logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a wrong class name activity in your Manifest.

Change it to

```
 <activity
        android:name="Gmapwithgps"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: @Kds if this answer helped you, click the little check mark in the top left hand corner of this post to accept this answer and mark the question as solved